# How to remove only fields I just added with Laravel migration?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-7

I'm adding these values to an existing table. In my `down()` function, how do I remove *only* the items I just added? `truncate()` will remove all the items in the table. I can use `DB::table('user_account_cancel_reasons')->where('action', '==', 'cancel')->delete();`, but that doesn't guarantee only removing the items in this migration. Using Laravel 7.

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddNewFieldsToUserAccountChangeReasons extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        DB::table('user_account_change_reasons')->insert(
            [
                [
                    'reason' => 'Health Issues',
                    'action' => 'cancel',
                    'created_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                    'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
                ],
                [
                    'reason' => 'Did not use',
                    'action' => 'cancel',
                    'created_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                    'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
                ],
                [
                    'reason' => 'Other',
                    'action' => 'cancel',
                    'created_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
                    'updated_at' => DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
                ],
             
            ]

        );
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('user_account_change_reasons', function(Blueprint $table) {
            DB::table('user_account_change_reasons')->truncate();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Migrations are typically for structure changes (adding, removing, renaming columns, etc.) to your database, not changes to records in the table. Also, unless you have some kind of unique identifier for the records being inserted, you won't be able to target those for removal later. You could do `DB::table('user_account_change_reasons')->whereIn('reason', ['Health Issues', 'Did not use', 'Other'])->delete()`, but if those `reason` values aren't unique, then you will get additional unwanted removals. Maybe add a unique field, like a `slug` that you can target for removal.

Comment: Write the `up()` function in reverse. So in `down()` first get the reasons you just created, and then delete them.

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah, I would think to write a seeder, but my company uses migrations in this way for some reason so I wanted to follow their pattern (I'm still a pretty new dev). I think adding a slug is the best bet since you're correct there are duplicate values. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Try, i solved it

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('user_account_change_reasons', function(Blueprint $table) 
        {
        DB::table('user_account_change_reasons')->where('action', 
          'cancel')->delete();
    });
}
```